# Restart button for my Window c# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to make a restart button for my current window but when I press it the window closes as it has to and the program stops on `gameWindow.Show()` with the following error: An unhandled exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException` occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Cannot set Visibility or call Show, `ShowDialog`, or `WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle` after a Window has closed.
I have a `GameWindow` and a `GameWindowViewModel`in which I create and `ICommand` for the restart button and a function.

**Here is the code I’m using:**

```
 void restartButtonClickFunction(object obj)
{
    GameWindow gamewindow = new GameWindow();
    foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window is GameWindow)
        {
            ((Window)window).Close();
        }
    }
    gamewindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: you want to restart the GameWindow from GameWindow itself?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want. I'm making a simple game and it has to have a Restart button in this Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, it is better to re-design your application. 
Instead of closing main window and showing it again, I suggest you to separate view models.

Create game view model:

```
public class GameVm : ViewModelBase
{
    public GameVm()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        health = rnd.Next(100);
        armor = rnd.Next(100);
    }

    public int Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set
        {
            if (health != value)
            {
                health = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private int health;

    public int Armor
    {
        get { return armor; }
        set
        {
            if (armor != value)
            {
                armor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private int armor;
}
```

and application view model:

```
public class ApplicationVm : ViewModelBase
{
    public ApplicationVm()
    {
        RestartGameCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Game = new GameVm());
        RestartGameCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    public GameVm Game
    {
        get { return game; }
        private set
        {
            if (game != value)
            {
                game = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private GameVm game;

    public ICommand RestartGameCommand { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, application manages game life cycle - when `RestartGameCommand` is fired, the game is re-created.

Now, this is how it will work at the view layer:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ApplicationVm />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Game view placeholder -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Game}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GameVm}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Health}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Armor}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
        <!-- Game controls pane -->
        <Button Content="Restart game" Command="{Binding RestartGameCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When handling `RestartGameCommand`, `ContentControl` inside view will be initialized with new game view model.

There's no any code, which manages window(s), but the game is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works
Not tested, a wild guess

```
void restartButtonClickFunction(object obj)
{

    foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window is GameWindow)
        {
            ((Window)window).Close();
        }
    }
    GameWindow gamewindow = new GameWindow();
    gamewindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: it closes the window and that's it. The program shuts down

Answer (score 0):

Error is telling you what is the problem. Your MainWindow is already closed so you cannot do other operations after that. Rather try to re-run the process itstead

```
void restartButtonClickFunction(object obj)
{
    Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Or you can use `EventAggregater` to raise event from `GameWindowViewModel` and listen that in `MainWindowViewModel` and there you can close and restart the GameWindow

Comment: that works fine but can it start from my GameWindow not my MainWindow?

Comment: GameWindow is being launched from MainWindow?

Comment: No. I have two views - MainWindow and GameWindow. In the GameWindowViewModel when I use your code and click the restart buton it takes me to the MainWindow. I want to take me again to a fresh GameWindow

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late here but I solved your problem. I'm currently doing the same thing but with the war card game. The code below is tested and it works.

```
private void Btn_reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      var newwindow = new Game_Window();
      newwindow.Show();
      Close();
}
```